# Hide / show the part of code using php, if the value contains the letters

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with this scenario. There is a certain field (textarea) - $ COMMENTS. If the information in the $COMMENTS starts with a number (the first is a number and then any letter) - the script works fine (hide / show "some HTML and PHP code"), but if the $COMMENTS starts with the letter - the code does not work at all. Please tell me what is my mistake. I suffer already the 5th day.

Here is the script code, unfortunately it did not work correctly:

```
<?php $comments=$hm->Zb('rs:def:comments');

if ($comments!=0): ?>

<div class="txt"><?php echo $hm->Zb('rs:def:comments'); ?></div>

<?php else : ?>
<div class="sorry">Sorry, there is no comments</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

also didn't work like this:

```
<?php $comments=$hm->Zb('rs:def:comments');

if ($comments!=""): ?>

<div class="txt"><?php echo $hm->Zb('rs:def:comments'); ?></div>

<?php else : ?>
<div class="sorry">Sorry, there is no comments</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Thank you all in advance for your help.

Comment: Try with `empty();` instead.

Comment: you forgot the $-sign in the `if-condition`

Comment: @RST thank you. add it)

Comment: @Epodax sorry didn't work properly. Didn't hide "div class" and didn't print "Sorry, there is no comments"

Comment: Did you do it like in Nitya Kumar's answer?

Comment: @Epodax. Yes i did! But Didn't hide "div class" and didn't print "Sorry, there is no comments"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `isset()` with `if()`

```
<?php $comments=$hm->Zb('rs:def:comments');

if (isset($comments)): ?>

<div class="txt"><?php echo $hm->Zb('rs:def:comments'); ?></div>

<?php else : ?>
<div class="sorry">Sorry, there is no comments</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**EDIT**

Please try below code.

```
<?php $comments=$hm->Zb('rs:def:comments');

echo $comments; //for debugging to ensure $comments have value.

if ($comments){ ?>

<div class="txt"><?php echo $hm->Zb('rs:def:comments'); ?></div>

<?php } else { ?>

<div class="sorry">Sorry, there is no comments</div>

<?php } ?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: sorry didn't work properly. Didn't hide "div class" and didn't print "Sorry, there is no comments"

Comment: try without isset `if($comments):` only

Comment: @Abhishek_gurjar even without isset didn't hide "div class" and didn't print "Sorry, there is no comments". (

Comment: Well then try if else with brackets and check $comments have value or not regardless of if else.

Comment: @Abhishek_gurjar.. Sorry can't understan you. Please make an example

Comment: Does $comments echoed which i written for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

try it : empty()

```
<?php $comments=$hm->Zb('rs:def:comments');

if (!empty($comments)): ?>

<div class="txt"><?php echo $hm->Zb('rs:def:comments'); ?></div>

<?php else : ?>
<div class="sorry">Sorry, there is no comments</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Didn't hide "div class" and didn't print "Sorry, there is no comments"